# How do I determine my Windows OS version with Rust?

Tags: rust

Can I use cfg to determine the OS Windows version for this block of code? The thing is that shcore lib is not available in windows 7 and below

```
#[cfg(all(windows, not(feature = "inline")))]
        unsafe {
        winapi::um::shellscalingapi::SetProcessDpiAwareness(2);
    }
```

Comment: The compiler will produce the same binary regardless of which version of windows you actually end up running it on. I think you'll have to do the check at runtime. e.g. you can invoke `systeminfo` and parse the result.